# Generating Externally Triggered Complimentary PWM with Arduino Due

Tags: interrupt, pwm, arduino-due, timers

- I need a 2KHz **complimentary** PWM waves with **adjustable duty and phase** that is triggered by an **external** 4KHz source.
- After reading the datasheet I think there might be 2 way to do this:

1. Use a TC unit in capture mode, and somehow generate an interrupt when the count reaches 2. Use another TC unit in waveform mode to output phase-correct PWM. Use yet another TC unit to implement dead-time and generate the complimentary PWM.
2. Use the PWM controller, which already have complimentary PWM with dead-time build-in, but I'm not sure if it accepts external trigger.

If either of them is possible, could you please provide and example code ?

Thanks in advance !